# show div on right click of element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to show div on click of right click event, this right click is working fine but event is not applied Correctly.

Fiddle::
http://jsfiddle.net/SRX3y/82/

Code::

```
$.event.special.rightclick = {
    bindType: "contextmenu",
    delegateType: "contextmenu"


};

$(document).on("rightclick", "div", function() {
    alert("hello");
    $('#popup').css('display','inline-block');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: `id="pop_up"`  but your selector is `$('#popup')` ???

Answer (score 3):

Try this..selector name is mistake.it should be `#pop_up`

```
$(document).on("rightclick", "div", function() {
    alert("hello");
    $('#pop_up').css('display','block');
    return false;
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SRX3y/83/)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine.

Just change from

```
$('#popup').css('display','inline-block');
```

to

```
$('#pop_up').css('display','inline-block');
```

Answer (score 2):

you have wrong id

Its `pop_up` and not `popup`